# AppAutoStartupPolicy: prevent start service of package com.farsitel.bazaar

Tags: android, in-app-billing, aidl

In app billing system with third-party after call context.bindService, it return with false and below log shown in log-cat:

```
AutoStartupDataMgr:isUnderControll third party not in whitelist: com.farsitel.bazaar
AppAutoStartupPolicy:ras app : com.farsitel.bazaar
AppAutoStartupPolicy:prevent start service of package com.farsitel.bazaar, serviceInfo ir.cafebazaar.data.pardakht.InAppBillingService by callerPid 14878, callerUid 10188
04-26 09:33:26.486 1814-30863/? W/ActivityManager_service: prevent by hsm Will not start service Intent { act=ir.cafebazaar.pardakht.InAppBillingService.BIND pkg=com.farsitel.bazaar } U=0: force null
04-26 09:33:26.486 1814-30863/? W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=ir.cafebazaar.pardakht.InAppBillingService.BIND pkg=com.farsitel.bazaar } U=0: not found
```

snippet calling code:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("ir.cafebazaar.pardakht.InAppBillingService.BIND");
serviceIntent.setPackage("com.farsitel.bazaar");
if (!mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(serviceIntent, 0).isEmpty()) {
    // service available to handle that Intent
    if(!mContext.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)){
        logDebug("Billing service binding error.");
        // ### always go here ####

        }
    }
}
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, When your application implements In-App-Billing must bind to a purchase service such as Google-play (or Cafebazaar in Iran) which is known as a third party furthermore third party application should be in Android white-list.
It's clear that your third-part application is not in the Android's White-list(As it said in the log). You can reinstall Cafebazaar (remove previous version and install new one) to fix the problem.

Comment: I reinstall it and solved my problem but I think this problem related to android os bug not target application:)

Comment: Maybe related to sanctions against Iran ;)

Comment: This does not solve problems relating to the prevention of other receiver.

Comment: @pikkuez my answer is for the asked question and resolved his problem at that time. if you have a new problem better to ask a new question.